# Диапазон перечислений enum

Tags: c++

Читаю Страуступа - Язык программирования C++, специальное издание, и хотел бы уточнить некоторые моменты.
На страницах 115 - 116 рассказывается по *диапазоны перечислений* (enum).
Цитата:

> Диапазон значений перечисления определяется следующим об­разом. Пусть
>   n - максимальное возможное значение элемента перечисления. Пусть n
>   такое минимальное целое, что 2^m-1 больше или равно n. Тогда верхняя
>   граница диапазона равна 2^m-1. Если наименьший элемент имеет
>   неотрицательное значение, нижняя гра­ница диапазона равняется нулю.
>   Если наименьшее значение элемента отрицательно, нижней границей
>   диапазона является наименьшая ближайшая отрицательная степень двойки
>   плюс 1. Таким образом, диапазон определяется минимальным количеством
>   бит, требуемым для представления значений всех элементов перечисления.
>   Например:
>
> enum el { dark, light }; // диапазон 0 : 1
>
> enum е2 {а = 3, b = 9 }; // диапазон 0 : 15
>
> еnum е3 { min = -10, max = 1000000 ); // диапазон -1048576 : 1048575

И всё здесь понятно, кроме одного:

> Если наименьшее значение элемента отрицательно, нижней границей
>   диапазона является наименьшая ближайшая отрицательная степень двойки
>   плюс 1.

Если смотреть третью строку примера:

> еnum е3 { min = -10, max = 1000000 ); // диапазон -1048576 : 1048575

То в случае с *max* понятно, почему диапазон 1048575, а вот в случае с *min* откуда берется граница -1048576 - не понятно. Если следовать правилам вычисления, т.е. ближайшая отрицательная степень двойки + 1 - то я никогда не получу значение -1048576.

Объясните пожалуйста, где и что я понимаю не так.

Comment: Страуструп писал много книг. Какую именно вы читаете?

Comment: @Harry изменил вопрос, добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно как-то непонятно написано.

Нижняя граница либо равна `0` (если отрицательных элементов нет), либо равна минус верхней границе минус 1.

Другими словами, `enum` может хранить те же значения, что и битовое поле минимальной длинны, достаточной для хранения всех констант в нем. [Источник](http://eel.is/c++draft/enum#dcl.enum-8).

Comment: Большое спасибо!